# How to right align a Vaadin 8 Grid column contents?

Tags: vaadin8

Looks like this question was answered for Vaadin 7, but solution does not work for Vaadin 8. 
[Right-align column contents in Vaadin Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291741/right-align-column-contents-in-vaadin-grid)
Grid setCellStyleGenerator method is not available anymore.

How can we align a column contents for Vaadin 8 Grid?

Comment: Add relevant code to your question please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grid.addColumn("property").setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-right");
```

Comment: setStyleGenerator is a method used to provide a CSS class that should be  used with given column